# VMWare Fusion: Unable to connect a Transcend USB 3.0 SD card reader

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, vmware, sd-card, vmware-fusion

I am unable to connect a Transcend USB 3.0 SD card reader to a VMware Fusion virtual machine running on my Mac laptop running OS X Catalina. I am using VMware Fusion version 11.5.3. I'm not sure it matters, but the guest OS is CentOS Enterprise Linux 8 64 bit.

I get the following error message:

```
The device 'Transcend' was unable to connect to its ideal host controller.
An attempt will be made to connect this device to the available host controller.
This might result in undefined behavior for this device.
```

I have tried some of the suggestions in [this VMware KB article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1027964), but to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to change the USB controller compatibility level to `USB 3.0` as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: The solution has actually been mentioned in [*External Hard Disk Connectivity in Ubuntu*](https://superuser.com/questions/660172/external-hard-disk-connectivity-in-ubuntu) in 2013, but that question didn’t mention the error message, so I arrived at this answer first. The screenshot is also helpful. Thank you!